# Select Value Option

Tags: javascript, select

I need help for this Select, I use this line of javascript code and it doesn't work.

```js
document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "291349";
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" style="width: 400px; background-color: rgb(235, 245, 251); color: black;" data-select2-id="select2-data-mySelect" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="97600" data-select2-id="select2-data-12-gt5z">Select White Background Front View Single Rectangular Object /// Angle View Countertop Microwaves // Select White Background Angle View Alcove Bathtubs / TE: 11s</option>
  <option value="251730" data-select2-id="select2-data-13-y5m5">Company Location Validation / TE: 11s</option>
  <option value="500103" data-select2-id="select2-data-14-rp9r">Categories Semantic Similarity V2.1 / TE: 10s</option>
  <option value="700321" data-select2-id="select2-data-15-1adt">Adult Content According To Google Adsense Rules / TE: 12s</option>
  <option value="27319" data-select2-id="select2-data-16-b3ab">Uathans Toxicity Experiment 4/ Uathens Toxicity Definition 6/ Abuse/Offense/Hate/Toxicity Annotation Experiment / TE: 10s</option>
  <option value="303712" data-select2-id="select2-data-17-3itz">Rate Content Of Animated Gifs (Adult Content) V2 / TE: 60s</option>
  <option value="45" data-select2-id="select2-data-18-b2nl">Facebook Page Discovery (En) V2 / TE: 60s</option>
  <option value="103969" data-select2-id="select2-data-19-tp8r">Is This A Sponsored Video? Youtube / TE: 30s</option>
  <option value="829272" data-select2-id="select2-data-20-rjc3">Judging Language Produced By An Artificial Intelligence (C) / TE: 61s</option>
  <option value="848300" data-select2-id="select2-data-21-teec">Find The Official Website Of Businesses JUNIO-22 / TE: 11s</option>
  <option value="902175" data-select2-id="select2-data-22-f1ll">Identify The Bill Of Lading Number (Cf Revision) / TE: 30s</option>
  <option value="291349" data-select2-id="select2-data-23-7edh">Are These Businesses The Same One? / TE: 15s</option>
  <option value="505317" data-select2-id="select2-data-24-e6jm">Find Urls For A Business In A Certain Site / Find Business Urls / TE: 30s</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap5 select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-1-qhy7" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-mySelect-container" aria-controls="select2-mySelect-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-mySelect-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Select White Background Front View Single Rectangular Object /// Angle View Countertop Microwaves // Select White Background Angle View Alcove Bathtubs / TE: 11s">Select White Background Front View Single Rectangular Object /// Angle View Countertop Microwaves // Select White Background Angle View Alcove Bathtubs / TE: 11s</span>
<span
  class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
  </span>
  </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
  <span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-mySelect-container" aria-controls="select2-mySelect-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-mySelect-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Select White Background Front View Single Rectangular Object /// Angle View Countertop Microwaves // Select White Background Angle View Alcove Bathtubs / TE: 11s">Select White Background Front View Single Rectangular Object /// Angle View Countertop Microwaves // Select White Background Angle View Alcove Bathtubs / TE: 11s</span>
  <span
    class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
    </span>
    </span>
```

I want to make an automatic selection with javascript but it doesn't work.

Comment: I converted your post to an executable snippet and it seems to work as desired.

Comment: Are you using the Select2 plugin? You might need to use its API to set the selected option, I'm not sure.

Comment: How are you calling your script? Could it be running before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: According to why the select is made with jquery that's why my code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question, but do you want the second-to-last option (291349) to be pre-selected in select? If so, I've tested your code and it's working. If not, please clarify further.

I copied your html code and put the script in a separate file. Then I called the file with the script in the html.

Comment: Here it works but on the web page the script does nothing

Comment: @LeonerCastillo is there an error in the console?

Comment: no error just does nothing